# Why does the ofstream << overload produce a different result when called as member function?

Tags: c++, char, operator-overloading, outputstream

Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << 'a'; // a
    operator << (std::cout, 'a'); // a
    std::cout.operator << ('a'); // 97
}
```

Compiled with commands:

```
g++.exe -Wall -g -Wall -std=c++11  -c <cpp file> -o <o file>
```

```
g++.exe <exe file> <o file>  -O0
```

Produces an output of `aa97` when executed.

It seems that for some reason calling the `operator <<` overload as a member function for `std::cout` invokes the template specialization for `int`, even if I passed a `char`. Is this right?

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 6):

There is no `operator<<` member operator for `std::basic_ostream` which has a `char` argument. You can see the list of member `operator<<` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt). The `char` overload is provided as a non-member operator `operator<<(basic_ostream<T>&, char)`. You can see the list of non-member `operator<<` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).

When you use `std::cout << 'a'` both non-member and member operators are considered, of which the `char` overload is chosen. But when you use `std::cout.operator<<('a')` only member operators are considered. It has to resort to an `int` overload.

Answer (score 2):

The class template std::basic_ostream has the following member operator

```
basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(int n);
```

but it does not have such a member for the type `char`.

For the type `char` there is a non-member template function

```
template<class traits>
basic_ostream<char, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char, traits>&, char);
```

So when you are using the member function then due to the integer promotions the argument of the type `char` is promoted to the type `int`

```
std::cout.operator << ('a');
```

But in this call

```
operator << (std::cout, 'a');
```

there is used the non-member template function

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that for some reason calling the `operator <<` overload as a member function for `std::cout` invokes the template specialization for `int`, even if I passed a `char`. Is this right?

Yes.

> Why does it happen?

It's because there is no [`std::ostream::operator<<(char)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) overload so it'll be using `std::ostream::operator<<(int)` after the `char` `'a'` has been converted to an `int` and `'a'` has the ASCII value 97.

Comment: I initially misread your answer. I have retracted my downvote. However your answer still fells like half the answer. Yes, it explains why `a` as `int` is `97`, but it doesn't explain why member operator call behaves differently.

Comment: @bolov Thanks, I reworded it a bit.